# Why is this script for Arbor.js not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arbor.js

Please help with the script; I don't understand why nothing is coming up on the page. I am just doing a test one to learn how Arbor.js works,but so far nothing has happened...
here's my code;

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/arbor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/arbor-tween.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="viewport" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000, 400,1);
        sys.parameters({gravity:true});
        sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport") ;
            var animals = sys.addNode('Animals',{'color':'red','shape':'dot','label':'Animals'});
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: you have to use type, like <script type="text/javascript" src="js/arbor.js"></script>

Comment: thanks :) but that didn't work...